# Prove this limit as $x\to\infty$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Let $f:(a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function. Suppose for each $b>a$, $f$ is bounded on $(a,b)$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)-f(x)=A$. Prove

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{x}=A.$$

Here we assume $f$ to be arbitrary and no further conditions. $f$ could be continuous,discontinuous,as long as it fits all assumptions. I have some trouble with the intermediate steps.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want to prove with $h$ is true.  Say $f(x)=Ax+\sin2\pi x$ (which fulfit all the initial conditions) but for any non-integer $h$ the limit does not exist.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón I see that. I am trying some other approaches

Comment: @Strants this question was asked in 2013, the one you mentioned in 2014. I'd close the other one!

Comment: @rtybase That's true, but I think the answer to the other question is more readable, so I'd rather readers see that one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have that $$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x+1)-f(x)=A$$ which means that for any $\varepsilon\in\mathbb R^+$ there is an $n\in\mathbb N$ such that for each $x>n$ then $A-\varepsilon<f(x+1)-f(x)<A+\varepsilon$.  (if we find some $n<a$ for this condition then we can chose $n=\lceil a\rceil$ for the remind of the proof.)

For simplicity I will define $g(x):=f(x)-Ax$, then we have that $g(x+1)-g(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)-A$ and for $x>n$: $|g(x+1)-g(x)|<\varepsilon$.

As $f$ is bounded in $(a,b)$ for any $b>a$, then $f$ is bounded in $(a,n+2)$ and as we have find $n\ge a$, then $f$ is bounded in $(n,n+1]$, let's call $\beta$ that boundary: $|f(x)|<\beta$ for any $x$ in $(n,n+1]$.
Also, let $\gamma=\beta+(n+1)|A|$, then  $g$ is bounded and $|g(x)|<\gamma$ for $x\in(n,n+1]$.

Now, we can prove that 
\begin{align}
|g(x)|&\le\gamma+(\lfloor x\rfloor-n)\varepsilon,&&\text{and}\\
\frac{|g(x)|}x &\le\frac{\gamma+(\lfloor x\rfloor-n)\varepsilon}x =\frac\gamma x+\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor-n}x\varepsilon
\end{align}

For any fixed positive $\varepsilon$, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac\gamma x+\frac{\lfloor x\rfloor-n}x\varepsilon=\varepsilon$$
therefor
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left|\frac{g(x)}x\right|=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{|g(x)|}x\le\varepsilon$$

This should prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{g(x)}x=0$, now the limit for $\frac{f(x)}x$ should follow by having $f(x)=Ax+g(x)$.

Comment: I don't think that the last step is valid, since $\beta$ is the bound of $f$ only for $x\in(n,n+1]$. But if $x>n+1$, we may not have this bound.

Comment: For $x>n+1$ we don't have the $\beta$ bound, but we have the $\varepsilon$ bound with respect to $x-1$, that's why I add $(\lfloor x\rfloor-n)\varepsilon$.

Comment: Oh!  I got a mistake as I forgave $A$.  I will edit and add $A$ where appropriate.

Comment: I think I understand now, because we have $|f(x+1)|<A+\varepsilon+|f(x)|$, and from this we can have what you deduced.